# window.location is not working with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I redirect to the main page during 2 scenarios

1. While the user hits logout
2. The session expires...

Logout functionality code...

```
 $("#logoutLink").click(Logout);
    function Logout() {
      $.post("Logout",
           { antiCSRF: '{{acsrf}}',
             session_id: '{{session_id}}'
        });
      alert("You are now securely logged out.");
      window.location = './';
    }
```

Session expiration code

```
function checksession() {

            $.post("CheckSession",
                     { antiCSRF : '{{acsrf}}',
                       session_id: '{{session_id}}'
                  },validateresult).fail(function() {alert("Session check failed")})

}



 function validateresult(result){
              if (result == "N"){
                valid_flag = "N"
                alert("Your session has been timed-out. Please click OK to be redirected to the login page to start a new session.");

                window.location = './';
              }
              else { valid_flag = "Y";
              return valid_flag
                }
            }
```

In the first case ie; when I hit the logout button the page is redirected to the main page without any issues...

But the code that gets executed during the ajax call does not work..ie; window.location is not working..

Not sure what is the difference between the

Comment: Very confusing what you are asking. Which ajax does not work? There are two ajax and both functions have a redirect.

Comment: @Hanlet: Both are ajax calls but in the second case i handle the response with a separate function call..First case works fine, but in the second case the redirection does not work...

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call is asynchronous.  You should show the alert() and perform the redirection in the callback function which is executed once the `$.post()` finishes:

```
$("#logoutLink").click(Logout);


function Logout() {
    $.post("Logout", {antiCSRF: '{{acsrf}}', session_id: '{{session_id}}'}, function() {
      alert("You are now securely logged out.");
      window.location = './';
    });
}
```